# reading in two text files and then combining them

Tags: c++, io, text-files

i'm having a problem making this code i wrote compile. this code is meant to read through two text files and then output the line inside both of these files. i then want to be able to put both files and combine them but with file1 text beeing on the first line and file2 text being on the line after that.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()

{

std::ifstream file1("file1.txt");
std::ifstream file2("file2.txt");
//std::ofstream combinedfile("combinedfile.txt");
//combinedfile << file1.rdbuf() << file2.rdbuf();


char filename[400];
string line;
string line2;

cout << "Enter name of file 1(including .txt): ";
cin >> filename;

file1.open(filename);
cout << "Enter name of file 2 (including .txt): ";
cin >> filename;

file2.open(filename);

  if (file1.is_open())
  {
    while (file1.good() )
    {
      getline (filename,line);
      cout << line << endl;

    }
   file1.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

 return 0;
}
 if (file2.is_open())
  {
    while (file2.good() )
    {
      getline (filename,line);
      cout << line << endl;
    }
   file2.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;}
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't do `while (file.good())` or `while (!file.eof())`, it won't work as expected. Instead do like e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

If you want to read and print alternate lines, there are two possible ways to do it:

1. Read both of the files into two `std::vector` objects, and the print from these vectors. Or possibly combine the two vectors into one vector, and print that.
2. Read one line from the first file and print it, then read from the second file and print that, in a loop.

The first alternative is probably the easiest, but uses the most memory.

For the second alternative, you could do something like this:

```
std::ifstream file1("file1.txt");
std::ifstream file2("file2.txt");

if (!file1 || !file2)
{
    std::cout << "Error opening file " << (file1 ? 2 : 1) << ": " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
    return 1;
}

do
{
    std::string line;

    if (std::getline(file1, line))
        std::cout << line;

    if (std::getline(file2, line))
        std::cout << line;

} while (file1 || file2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
cout << ifstream(filename1, ios::in | ios::binary).rdbuf();
cout << ifstream(filename2, ios::in | ios::binary).rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second if-Statement is outside of the main()-function. After the first return 0; you close the main()-function. 
Another issue in your code is, that you will never reach the second if-Statement if it is inside the main()-function, because the the return 0; ends the main().
I guess you just want to execute return if the first filestream is "bad", so you need a scope for the else;